# Jenkins - Process exists, but I can't see the UI

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson, jenkins, testcomplete

I'm trying to force a custom tool to run through Jenkins for testing.  I've created a sample program, Calculator, and need to run it through TestComplete.  My call as a batch is:

```
START "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Build\workspace\Calculator\bin\Release\Calculator.exe"

"c:\Program Files (x86)\Automated QA\TestComplete 8\Bin\TestComplete.exe" "c:\Users\AaronH\Documents\CI Implementation\DEV\Test Tool Engine\TestComplete\AutomationFramework.pjs" /r /e /ns /SilentMode "TestSet=1"
```

I can see Calculator and TestComplete in the process tree, however, there is no UI that appears.  It's being run under SYSTEM.  Because this is the case, I can't tell if anything is working the way it should.  Is there a way to start these under my user or to verify they are actually working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/My+software+builds+on+my+computer+but+not+on+Jenkins especially under the title "Desktop Access"